# how to put a html as a link on fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am doing a site of vaping recipes and i want that on the tab of "recipes" to show images of the recipes but when you click on that, it shows a window with the recipe.I am doing tests with **fancybox**, i`ll put the jquery files on mega to download, and show here the code i use.
 The problem is that I can't use other thing that is not a img and I want to load a page or at least a window where i can show the info of a data base (like the title and recipe uploaded from other user) instead of the second image it shows when you click the first one, the page is like (stack overflow doesnt let me post the images so i would try to do it on a comment of the post)
[how it looks like]
and then when you click one, 
[pressed one of the images]
do you know hoy to put a html to load at the second part? would be awesome... 
or at least something that does that... 
link on mega of the code: [Mega zip file](https://mega.nz/#!HVAlQabC!N5ZaJ6L6UHgutK-76oTN7SPCmutkCwldkMlY_i7c9gE)
Thanks a lot and the part I use the image transitions

```
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="../Home/Home.html"><img class="resize" src="2.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group2" href="3.jpg"><img class="resize" src="4.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group3" href="5.jpg"><img class="resize" src="6.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

PS: Sorry for my strange english I am spanish and I am doing an effort to explain myself as well as I can....

Comment: Image number 1: http://es.tinypic.com/r/3462j2c/9

Comment: Image number 2: http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=t0sv1z&s=9

Comment: The idea it's something like the recipes of "el gnomo vapeador": http://elgnomovapeador.com/index.php?id_category=51&controller=category